# separating visual studio WPF designer panels

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to completely separate (as in to have them on different windows on different screens) the XAML and Design tabs of the WPF designer in Visual Studio? I've been looking vut haven't found it..

Answer (score 0):

You can open two instances of Visual Studio and open same file, one in xaml and another in design mode.

Comment: Unfortunately not really a viable solution, then I'll constantly have to click Ctrl+S to save changes in one and then click 'Yes' as an answer to the file modified, wanna reload? dialog in the second one.